# Simple loop not displaying data

Tags: php

This is puzzling the hell out of me ..
Simple fetch & loop isn't displaying any data
There is data in the table as displaying the result outside the loop returns data

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect($dbh, $dbu, $dbp, $dbn);
$query = mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT * FROM `products`");
$res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
$rows = array();
do {
    $rows[] = $res['product'];

}while($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) ;
$data = json_encode($rows);
echo $data;
echo mysqli_error($dbc);
```

ADDED :

returns the data in the array

```
<pre>Array
(
    [ID] => 1
    [list_name] => Dry Fruits
    [cat] => Dry Fruits and Nuts
    [item_code] => 1049
    [pack_style] => 106
    [packstyle_active] => Y
    [style_desc] => Stabilo250
    [system_wt] => 0.25
    [weight_desc] => 250gm
    [declared_weight] => 0.25
    [declared_weight_desc] => 250gm
    [uom] => gm
    [qty_in_case] => 1
    [case_size] => 1 x 250gm
    [product] => Almond Sliced
    [weight_code] => 126
    [qty_code] => 00
    [product_code] => 1049-106-126-00
    [barcode] => 502185878567
    [barcode13] => 5021858785678
    [sequence_no] => 78567
    [sage_code] => 104978567
    [active] => N
    [allergen] => Y
    [origin] => Various
    [density] => 0
    [processtype] => PT32
    [processed_by] => FGS
    [Industrial] => N
    [Catering] => N
    [RetailEthnic] => Y
    [RetailMainstream] => N
    [Website] => N
    [Special] => N
    [zohoitemcode] => 1540890000001353073
)
```

So I think its an issue with the json_encode.. maybe

```
    print_r($rows) 
    Array
   (
    [0] => Almond Sliced
    [1] => Almond Sliced
    [2] => Almond Sliced
    [3] => Almond Sliced
    [4] => Almond Sliced
    [5] => Almond Sliced
    [6] => Almond Sliced
    [7] => Almond Sliced
    [8] => Almond Sliced
    [9] => Almond Sliced
    [10] => Almond Sliced
    [11] => Almond Sliced
    [12] => Almond Sliced
    [13] => Almond Sliced
    [14] => Almond Sliced
    [15] => Almond Sliced
    )
```

There is over 36000 records of products

Comment: Are there more rows to fetch? What is `var_dump($query)`?

Comment: your code is ok. can you show your desired output.

Comment: `$res` does exist inside loop because it is declared in line 3.

Comment: Doesn't `$rows[] = $res['product']` create a numerical index? Your `print_r($rows)` output doesn't look like that. How can that `print_r` be the result of your loop?

Comment: sorry that was the output form something someone requested  i just forgot to remove the print_r reference

Comment: Are you getting any error because I tried your code and works perfectly.

Comment: thats the annoying thing .. no errors whatsoever 
If i do a print_r($rows) I get every product listed , Thats why I think it might be something wrong with the json_encode

Comment: Are you using this page for `ajax` request?

Comment: nope for a script to pass into zoho.. but there is nothing else on this page at all which could be causing it to behave like this

Comment: put a limit in your query then try again.

Comment: ive been running this with limit 3000 while ive been doing all the tests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appeared to be a strange encoding issue.  Added a line in the while loop to force the encoding to UTF-8.

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect($dbh, $dbu, $dbp, $dbn);
$query = "SELECT * FROM `products`";
$stmt = $dbc->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$results = $stmt->get_result();

while($res = $results->fetch_assoc()){

  $rows[] = mb_convert_encoding($res['product'], 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');

}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($rows);
echo '</pre>';

$data = json_encode($rows);
echo $data;

echo mysqli_error($dbc);
```

Comment: still the same @Joseph_J

Comment: It appears that your query is only returning 1 product.

Comment: Yeah which is annoying because there are 36000 records
If i do a simple echo $res['product']; inside the do while loop it returns them all

Comment: See Updated answer.

Comment: just got null returned

Comment: `$data = json_encode($res)` is encoding `$res` when it's false. You must have meant to encode `$rows`.

Comment: Yeah I spotted that and changed to $rows in my code

Comment: @D.Go Thanks for pointing that out.  Updated... Did that fix it for ya?

Comment: nope .. I spotted your error and used $rows in my code.. still same issue

Comment: So print_r($rows) is displaying the information correctly?

Comment: yep as many records as I want it to using LIMIT will post snippet of results above

Comment: So what is the problem then?  If `$rows` is printing out ok then you have your data.  What does the `echo $data;` produce for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185057/discussion-between-joseph-j-and-chris-yates).

Comment: echo $data doesnt seem to be doing anything .. I need the data json encoded

Comment: cheers :) stupid encoding issue ..

Answer (score 0):

Try change your loop to the following:

```
foreach($res as $val) {
    $rows[] = $val['product'];
}
```

Moreover, if it still doesn't work. then:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_($res);
die();
```

and please post the output.

Edit: 1

You don't need foreach loop.

you can directly do:

```
$data = json_encode($res);
echo $data;
```

Comment: Am getting Warning: Illegal string offset 'product' in line 21 thats the $rows[] = $val['product']; line.
Will try your last suggestion now

Comment: You are getting it because you don't have a key named `product` in your array.

Comment: have just added the output you requested

Comment: did you try the changes I updated in answer?

Comment: yeah the last suggestion you made just outputted 1 product

Comment: I have changed foreach loop. Try it.

Comment: still the Illegal string offset 'product'  error

Comment: `foreach` loop will not work because `$res` contains only one row.